# Move & Rotate an UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation, move

I have an UIImageView with an rotation animation that loops, I need to move the UIImageView by x and y in the screen.

The rotation animation code is:

```
-(void)rotate{

if (leftRotate){
    leftRotate = NO;
}else{
    leftRotate = YES;
}

CGRect initFrame = self.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{

                     if (leftRotate){
                         self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, -1 * (M_PI/8));
                     }else{
                         self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, M_PI / 8);
                     }

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed) {
                     if (completed){
                         if (!stopRotate){
                             [self rotate];
                         }
                     }
                 }];
}
```

I try differents approaches to move the image, like setting the center but I cant move it.

Comment: You can also use a CGAffineTransformConcat to combine a CGAffineTransformRotate and CGAffineTransformTranslate into one transformation and apply that

Comment: I have to combine them in the same animation? , I need to move the UIImageView, out side the animation.

Comment: I can move the UIImageView using self.face1.center setting x and y, the problem now Is If I try to set the center inside -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event, for some reason, the center not change.

Comment: what causes your problems is that you use UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat - when you have this on, the code in the animations:^{.....} block does not get evaluated every time (which you can verify if you throw an NSLog statement in there, it gets printed just once) . You're recalling rotate method at the end of the animation already, so why have a UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat option on?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way, I have to set the center out side the animation:

```
CGPoint facePosition = CGPointMake(self.face1.center.x+1,
                                 self.face1.center.y);

self.face1.center = facePosition;
```